# How to determine changed attributes on after_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I can't catch the changed attributes on after_save callback but I can catch them on after_update callback. I think after_save is just a combination of after_create and after_update. I'd appreciate it if someone give me at least a hint.

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord

  after_save: after_save_callback


  def after_save_callback
    if username_changed?  ### This is always false
      # do something
    end
  end

end
```

```
student = Student.create(name: 'John Doe', username: 'abcdef')

student.username = '123456'
student.save
```

My Rails version is 5.0.7.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `saved_change_to_username?`

The behavior of `attribute_changed?` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_change_to_attribute?` instead.